# JSP modyfing collections values from checkboxes

Tags: jsp

I completely have no idea how can I force JSP to modify values in collection.

I have code like this (the most important part - I think):

```
            <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${formObject.userList}" var="list" varStatus="cnt">
            <c:set var="idx" value="${cnt.index}"/>
            <tr>
                <td class="moduleCode">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${list.userType == 'OW'}"> <spring:message
                                code="manage-flow.user.message.ow"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${list.userType == 'CO'}"> <spring:message
                                code="manage-flow.user.message.co"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${list.userType == 'RE'}"> <spring:message
                                code="manage-flow.user.message.re"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${list.userType == 'JU'}"> <spring:message
                                code="manage-flow.user.message.ju"/>
                        </c:when>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
                <td class="moduleCheckbox">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="s-${idx}"
                               <c:if test="${list.availA}">checked</c:if>
                               <c:if test="${!formObject.edited}">disabled</c:if> />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class=" moduleCheckbox">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="se-${idx}"
                               <c:if test="${list.availP}">checked</c:if>
                               <c:if test="${!formObject.edited}">disabled</c:if> />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="moduleCheckbox">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ser-${idx}"
                               <c:if test="${list.availC}">checked</c:if>
                               <c:if test="${!formObject.edited}">disabled</c:if> />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
```

some of them are already checked, and some not (I am reading from DB) and setting this up.

Now, we have situation like this. I have an unchecked checkbox and i am clicking it to check him. And after clicking save button, the formObject send is unchanged (it is exactly the same, as it comes from DB), and so I am updating row in DB with same values...

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, which is working for me.

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${formObject.userList}" var="list" varStatus="cnt">
    <c:set var="idx" value="${cnt.index}"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="moduleCode">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${list.userType == 'OW'}"> <spring:message
                        code="manageUser-flow.user.message.ow"/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${list.userType == 'CO'}"> <spring:message
                        code="manageUser-flow.user.message.co"/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${list.userType == 'RE'}"> <spring:message
                        code="manageUser-flow.user.message.re"/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${list.userType == 'JU'}"> <spring:message
                        code="manageUser-flow.user.message.ju"/>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        </td>
        <td class="moduleCheckbox">
            <div>
                <c:if test="${!formObject.edit}">
                    <form:checkbox path="userList[${idx}].availA"
                                   cssClass="checkbox" value="true" disabled="true"/>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${formObject.edited}">
                    <form:checkbox path="userList[${idx}].availA"
                                   cssClass="checkbox" value="true"/>
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class=" moduleCheckbox">
            <div>
                <c:if test="${!formObject.edit}">
                    <form:checkbox path="userList[${idx}].availP"
                                   cssClass="checkbox" value="true" disabled="true"/>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${formObject.edited}">
                    <form:checkbox path="userList[${idx}].availP"
                                   cssClass="checkbox" value="true"/>
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="moduleCheckbox">
            <div>
                <c:if test="${!formObject.edit}">
                    <form:checkbox path="userList[${idx}].availC"
                                   cssClass="checkbox" value="true" disabled="true"/>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${formObject.edited}">
                    <form:checkbox path="userList[${idx}].availC"
                                   cssClass="checkbox" value="true"/>
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```